# matlab regular expression to check if variables are set in a script

Tags: regex, matlab

To check if one or more variables (like `var1, var2, ...`) are set in the script, I read the script into a list of strings (line by line) and check if a line looks like

```matlab
var1=...
[var1,x]=...
[var2,x]=...
[x,y,var1,z]=...
```

Currently I'm use the following pattern

```matlab
pattern = '^([.*)?(var1|var2|var3)(.*])?=';
ix = regexp(s,pattern,'once');
```

It works for my purpose but I know it's not a safe pattern, because something like `[x,vvvar1,y]=...` also matches the pattern.

My current solution is to make separate patterns for each type of expressions, but I wonder if there is a unique pattern that can meet my needs.

---

Here are some examples, if I want to match any of `abc` or `def`,

```
pattern = '^([.*)?(abc|def)(.*])?=';

%% good examples
regexp('x=1',pattern,'once') % output []
regexp('aabc=1',pattern,'once') % output []
regexp('abc=1',pattern,'once') % output 1
regexp('[other,abc]=deal(1,2)',pattern,'once') % output 1

%% bad examples
regexp('[x,aabcc]=deal(1,2)',pattern,'once') % output 1
regexp('[x,abcc,y]=deal(1,2,3)',pattern,'once') % output 1
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : MATLAB regex is weird, OP's expression certainly works in MATLAB. The duplicate you linked might be useful to fix what you thought was an error, but it doesn't answer OP's question at all.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried it out, it does what is expected, it works correctly. Honestly, MATLAB's implementation of regex is **weird**.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew My Q is not related to whether `[` should be escaped...

Comment: So, what is the problem? Please clarify what the problem is. What are the exact pattern requirements? Check `^\[?(var1|var2|x|y|z)(,(var1|var2|x|y|z))*]?=` [regex example](https://regex101.com/r/a7WrmC/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no, `pat='^\[?(abc|def)(,(abc|def))*]?='; regexp('[xx,abc,yy]=deal(1,2,3)',pat,'once')` is a counterexample.

Comment: But of course, you need to add all the alternatives in the groups, else, there will be no match. If you do not know all of them, you need to be able to consume them in order to skip. Something like `^\[?(\w+,)*\b(abc|def)\b(,\w+)*]?=`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/a7WrmC/2).

Comment: Why add `\b`? Only without `\b` it works.

Comment: Sorry, correct, `\b` is redundant from all angles.

Comment: I thinks now it works. You can turn it to A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make sure there is at least one specific variable in the string.

You can use

```js
^\[?(\w+,)*(abc|def)(,\w+)*]?=
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a7WrmC/3).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\[?` - an optional literal `[` char
- `(\w+,)*` - zero or more one or more word chars + a comma sequences
- `(abc|def)` - either `abc` or `def`
- `(,\w+)*` - zero or more comma + one or more word chars sequences
- `]?` - an optional `]` char
- `=`  - a `=` char.